# How to drag and Drop a view from image view to a listview?

Tags: android

> I have image view on left side and a list view on right side. I want to drag the image view from left side to list view in right side. I have seen many examples in which a view can be moved from one view to another, provided all lies in the same layout. My problem arises here.  My list view and image view both are in different layout. Also for tablet design, both image view and list view are in different fragments. So how can I drag and Drop image from one fragment to another. Could anyone guide me to the right way to do it in both cases. Any help in this case is highly appreciable.